# Go: understanding strings

Tags: string, go

I got slightly confused this morning when the following code worked.

```
// s points to an empty string in memory
s := new(string)

// assign 1000 byte string to that address
b := make([]byte, 0, 1000)
for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
    if i%100 == 0 {
        b = append(b, '\n')
    } else {
        b = append(b, 'x')
    }
}
*s = string(b)

// how is there room for it there?
print(*s)
```

http://play.golang.org/p/dAvKLChapd

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here. Some insight would be appreciated.

Comment: The line *s = string(b) assigns s to a new string. This discards the old object you made in your second line.

Comment: @FUZxxl I was thinking in terms of C strings, which seems obviously wrong in retrospect.

Comment: In Go, a string is already a reference type, just as a slice is.

Comment: To make it simpler, you can just consider `t := ""; t = string(b); print(t) // how is there room for it there?` where `t` is the `*s`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I hope I understood the question...

An entity of type string is implemented by a run time struct, roughly

```
type rt_string struct {
        ptr *byte // first byte of the string
        len int   // number of bytes in the string
}
```

The line

```
*s = string(b)
```

sets a new value (of type rt_string) at *s. Its size is constant, so there's "room" for it.

More details in rsc's [paper](http://research.swtch.com/godata).